# Сформировать html с помощью python

Tags: html, python, format

Есть у меня замечательный лист туплов (в принципе могу переделать на лист листов, на словарь листов и вообще на всё, что угодно. Это не принципиально):

```
lst = [(['her1'], [lol1]), (['her2'], [lol2, 123, lol4]), (['her3'], [lol3324, 555])]
```

Тут оно как str так и int попадается...

И есть переменная с html с помощью которой я хочу сделать таблицу:

```html
html = """<html>

<body>
  <br></br>
  <FONT size=4><B>Hello!</B></FONT>
  <br></br>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <B>ROW1</B>
      </td>
      <td>
        <B>ROW2</B>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>ololo</td>
      <td>tralala</td>
    </tr>


  </table>
  <BR />
  <FONT size=4><B> Bye! </B></FONT>
  <BR>
  </B>
  </FONT>
  <BR />
</body>

</html>"""
```

Мне нужно вместо этих ololo и tralala вставить her и lol соответственно. То есть придётся делать примерно так:

```html
html = """<html>
<body>
<br></br>
<FONT size=4><B>Hello!</B></FONT>
<br></br>
<table border=1>
 <tr>
   <td><B>ROW1</B></td>
   <td><B>ROW2</B></td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>her1</td>
  <td>lol1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>her2</td>
  <td>lol2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>her3</td>
  <td>lol3, lol324, lol2131</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
   <BR />
   <FONT size=4><B> Bye! </B></FONT><BR>
   </B></FONT><BR />
 </body>
</html>"""
```

Вот как мне это сделать с помощью python? 
P.S. В листе, разумеется, в тысячи раз больше her и lol, если это важно ...

Answer (score 1):

Можно было бы использовать шаблонизатор, и если у вас таких документов много - это будет самый разумный выход (см. jinja2). Но если задача одна, то можно и проще, например так:

```
lst = [(['her1'], ['lol1']), (['her2'], ['lol2', 'lol3', 'lol4'])]

doc_template = '''
<html>

<body>
  <br></br>
  <FONT size=4><B>Hello!</B></FONT>
  <br></br>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <B>ROW1</B>
      </td>
      <td>
        <B>ROW2</B>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {rows}
  </table>
  <BR />
  <FONT size=4><B> Bye! </B></FONT>
  <BR>
  </B>
  </FONT>
  <BR />
</body>

</html>
'''

row_template = '''
    <tr>
      <td>{header}</td>
      <td>{values}</td>
    </tr>
'''

document = doc_template.format(
    rows=''.join(row_template.format(
        header=', '.join(header),
        values=', '.join(values)
    ) for header, values in lst)
)

print document
```

Comment: э-э-э-э, пардон, моя вина, не сказал, что там могут быть только цифры. В общем, TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found. Если писать str(header) и str(values), то он каждый символ разбивает отдельно запятой :(

Comment: `', '.join(map(str, values))`  можно.

Comment: Ага, пасиба большое, я там просто числа в листе изначально начал в str переделывать. А такой костыльный способ мне нужен чтоб одно только письмо отправить, так что я не стал устанавливать всякие модули и шаблонизаторы, остановился на Вашем варианте. Спасибо за потраченное время!

Answer (score -1):

Есть такой вариант:

```
table = [(['her1'], ['lol1']), (['her2'], ['lol2', 'lol3', 'lol4']), (['her3'], ['lol3324', 'lol434423'])]

print('<table>')
for row in table:
  print('<tr>')
  for ceil in row:
    print('<td>', ', '.join(ceil), '</td>')
  print('</tr>')
print('</table>')
```

По-хорошему, нужно использовать какой-нибудь шаблонизатор для этого.

Comment: Спасибо за потраченное время!